# RchivalTag package date

Tags: r, date, time

I am trying to use the RchivalTag package in R and I am having issues with the date and time. Whenever I try to use read_histos() it gives me the following error:

```
hist_dat_1<- read_histos(Georgia)
Warning: 598 parsing failures.
row col                    expected              actual
  1  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2009-02-23 00:00:00
  2  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2009-02-23 06:00:00
  3  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2009-02-23 12:00:00
  4  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2009-02-23 18:00:00
  5  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2009-02-24 00:00:00
... ... ........................... ...................
See problems(...) for more details.

Error in .fact2datetime(as.character(add0$Date), date_format = date_format,  : 
  date concersion failed! Please revise current'date_format': %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y to 2009-02-23 00:00:00
```

Current date/time class:

```
class(Georgia$Date)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I have changed the date and time format to:

```
format(Georgia$Date, format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
```

But I am still getting the error message. If anyone is familiar with this package, help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one without reproducible data, but we can actually replicate your error using one of the package's built-in data sets:

```r
library(RchivalTag)

hist_file <- system.file("example_files/67851-12h-Histos.csv",package="RchivalTag")
Georgia <- read.csv(hist_file)
```

This reads the histogram data in as a data frame, which seems to be the stage you are at. We will, however, change the format to POSIXct standard date-time representation.

```r
Georgia$Date <- strptime(Georgia$Date, "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
Georgia$Date <- as.character(Georgia$Date)
```

Now when we try to read the data we get:

```r
read_histos(Georgia)
#> Warning: 34 parsing failures.
#> row col                    expected              actual
#>   1  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2012-02-01 08:10:00
#>   2  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2012-02-01 12:00:00
#>   3  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2012-02-02 00:00:00
#>   4  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2012-02-02 12:00:00
#>   5  -- date like %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y 2012-02-03 00:00:00
#> ... ... ........................... ...................
#> See problems(...) for more details.
#> 
#> Error in .fact2datetime(as.character(add0$Date), date_format = date_format,  : 
#>   date concersion failed! Please revise current'date_format': %H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y to 2012-02-01 08:10:00
```

To fix this, we can rewrite the Date column using `strftime`:

```r
Georgia$Date <- strftime(Georgia$Date, "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
```

And now we can read the data without the parse errors.

```r
read_histos(Georgia)
#>   DeployID   Ptt Type p0_25 p0_50 p0_75 p0_90
#> 1    67851 67851  TAD   2.9   100   100   100
#> 2    67851 67851  TAT   3.0   100   100   100
```